# Moved from site.com:8080 to port 80 with lighttpd. Need help redirecting

Tags: redirect, port, lighttpd

I have a site that people put links on their pages to get to my site. There a several hundred sites out there with mysite.com:8080/url on them. I no longer use the program that answered on 8080 and just have lighttpd listening on port 80. The new php program looks at the referring url to know what the site was. I need to redirect all the mysite.com:8080 whatevers to mysite.com keeping the referring information. Sounds simple but I cant get it to work. If I use iptables to redirect 8080 to 80 lighttpd doesn't direct them to any particular site (there are several sites on the server using the hosts variable to determine what to direct people to). Its like its stripping the referring information off before it gets to lighttpd. Ive searched and searched and I cant find a solution.

Hoping someone here can help please.

Comment: I knew I had seen that somewhere: would this help ? http://serverfault.com/questions/180800/how-to-permanently-redirect-port-8080-url-to-port-80-using-nginx

Comment: The only problem is I cant figure out how to put that in my lighttpd config. That's for ngix which is close but not the same.

Comment: I am very sorry, I read lighttpd and thought nginx. I have added a possible answer below with lighttpd.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a configuration like this one. Basically, redirecting to port 80 anything coming into 8080.

```
server.port = 80
...
$SERVER["socket"] == ":8080" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "([^:/]+)" {
        url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://%1/$1" )
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok that worked great to get it to serve the root document but it isn't following the $host directives to go to the site.

Comment: Sorry for the extra comments but when I hit return it post the comment... Its not following the $host directives when :8080 is on the end of the url. Which I would think it should. I guess the redirect is stripping the part out where it would know what url was being asked for?

Comment: This part is being ignore $HTTP["host"] =~ mysite.com etc

Comment: Ok this worked but its not causing the referrer info to be passed so site doesn't know where the person came from.  : $SERVER["socket"] == ":8080" {
 server.document-root = "/home/mysite/public_html"
url.rewrite-once = ( "^/(.*)" => "/index.php" )
}
The old software had info on the end of the url I have to strip and point at index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I basically ended up replicating the other section for the normal site inside the :8080 part.

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":8080" {
 server.document-root = "/home/mysite/public_html"
url.rewrite-once += ( "^/(.*)" => "/index.php" )
evasive.max-conns-per-ip = 10
server.error-handler-404 = "/e404.php"
}
```

The key to getting the referer information to make it thru was add + to the url rewrite.

was :

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "^/(.*)" => "/index.php" )
```

fix needed to be :

```
url.rewrite-once += ( "^/(.*)" => "/index.php" )
```

Working perfectly now. Thanks for the help and wanted to post my final solution in case it helps someone else one day.

Thanks again.